# Equation to center div that is offset in browser window using translateX withOUT absolute positioning

Tags: jquery, css, math

I have a `div` that its width is calculated on page load and set to the total width of all the items in it.

This `div` lives inside another `div` that sits center on the screen with a `max-width` of `1280px`.

For our example lets say this:

```js
let element = 1680,
    container = 1240,
    browserWidth = 1878,
    targetLeft,
    offsetLeft = (el) => {
        if (element > container) {
          targetLeft = ((element - container) / 2) * -1;
        } else {
          targetLeft = ((container - element) / 2);
        }
        $(el).css({
            'transform': 'translateX(' + targetLeft + 'px)',
            'width': element + 'px'
        });
    };

offsetLeft('.element');
```

```css
html, body {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper {
    background-color: green;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1280px;
    padding: 20px;
}
.element {
    font-size: 0;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateX(0);
}
.item {
    background-color: gray;
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="element">
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
                <div class="item"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to apply `transform: translateX(-X);` to the `.element` in order for it to sit in the middle of the browser window whether its smaller/larger or not.

note: manually started adding values in CSS to see what the result would be and it comes out to `220` but since I did it manually I'm not sure what the equation is to get that result dynamically.

**UPDATED: I was able to figure it out, i updated the code snippet above with the working code!**

Comment: Maybe for the benefit of other users you may want to add an answer with the updated code?

Comment: Updated the code above.